# How to force app to end if user disable their internet connection during running of app?

Tags: java, android

I want to  force app to end  if user disable his internet connection during running of app
I tried this code and work good at the begining of app but when I disable internet during running it isnt closed!
this is my code

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_reg);

    if(!isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish(); //Calling this method to close this activity when internet is not available.
    }
  register_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerbtn);
    register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(LogRegActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    login_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
    login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i =new Intent(LogRegActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

}

this is my build.gradle when i used broadcast receiver it shows that using reciever is deprecated for N or higher how can i fix this problem??

```
   <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.amr.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: Use broadcast receiver for achieve this.

Comment: Can you post the code for it

Comment: post the code, have check it!

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcast receiver for connectivity change, here is steps for achieve this:

Step 1 : register receiver in manifest.xml

```
 <receiver android:name="NetworkChangeReceiver ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Step 2 : Create broadcast receiver :

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        if(checkInternet(context))
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Network Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }

    }

    boolean checkInternet(Context context) {
        ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(context);
        if (serviceManager.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Step 3 : Broadcast receiver which will handle network change:

```
public class HandleNetwork extend AppcompatActivity{

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        registerNetworkBroadcastForNougat();


    }

 private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
             //logic on network enable
        } else {
             //logic on network disable
        }


 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        if (context == null) return false;
        try {
            ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService
                    (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()
                    .isAvailable() && connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }


//Register receiver 

 private void registerNetworkBroadcastForNougat() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver , new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver , new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        }
    }

    protected void unregisterNetworkChanges() {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mNetworkReceiver);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterNetworkChanges();
    }
}

}
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: is this for all vesrions or nougat only.??

Comment: yes, this will work in all version. did you try this?

Comment: I am trying right noe and will tell you whether it works or not after implementing

Comment: hello plz check my edit it says that this is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a broadcast receiver for CONNECTIVITY_ACTION. There you can check for the state of the connection.

Also see [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring#MonitorChanges).

Comment: sir, my code is already working but when activity is created, but during running when i close internet activity still running. also i checked docs i found that it is the same of my code

Comment: so how can i register this CONNECTIVITY_ACTION if it will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one activity and and open that activity with following flags and then finish it by calling `finish()` in `onCreate()` of created activity.

add following code where you are checking internet connectivity

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, NoInternetActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)))
```

in `NoInternetActivity` activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        finish();
 }
```

and don't forget to add `NoInternetActivity` in manifest